# Change google sheet tab name based on time trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently using a script that works perfectly to change the tab name based on onEdit.  Here's the script:

```
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('CONTROL PANEL')
const sheet2 = ss.getSheets()[1]
const sheet3 = ss.getSheets()[2]
const sheet4 = ss.getSheets()[3]
const sheet5 = ss.getSheets()[4]
const sheet6 = ss.getSheets()[5]
const sheet7 = ss.getSheets()[6]
const sheet8 = ss.getSheets()[7]
const sheet9 = ss.getSheets()[8]

function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == sheet1.getSheetId() 
  && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B2') sheet2.setName(e.value);
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == sheet1.getSheetId() 
  && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'E2') sheet3.setName(e.value);
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == sheet1.getSheetId() 
  && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B8') sheet4.setName(e.value);
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == sheet1.getSheetId() 
  && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'E8') sheet5.setName(e.value);
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == sheet1.getSheetId() 
  && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B14') sheet6.setName(e.value);
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == sheet1.getSheetId() 
  && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'E14') sheet7.setName(e.value);
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == sheet1.getSheetId() 
  && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B20') sheet8.setName(e.value);
  if (e.range.getSheet().getSheetId() == sheet1.getSheetId() 
  && e.range.getA1Notation() == 'E20') sheet9.setName(e.value);
}
```

Instead of onEdit.. I want this script to run on a time based trigger.  How do I change it so that it runs on a time based trigger?  What part of the script do I need to change?

Comment: What is the difference between the two trigger event objects?

Comment: The cells being called will be changed based on a formula and not a manual edit.  I need to time trigger to check the cells to see if the cell value changed and trigger the name change.

Comment: What's the formula?

Comment: It’s pulling the value from another cell that’s using import range from another sheet.  So the formula for one is =D1 but cell D1 is using an import range formula to call information from a different sheet.

Comment: We can't help if you can tell us what you want.

Comment: I don’t understand how I’m not telling you what I want. I want the tab name to change for a sheet based on the value of cell B2.  However cell B2 will change based on an import range value from a separate sheet.  Cell B2 will pull from cell D1. Cell D1 is using import range to pull information from a separate sheet.  So I want to set a time trigger to change the tab name based on the value of B2.

Comment: Which tab? Will the name of the be the value of B2?

Comment: The second tab of the sheet will be the name of the value of B2.  That’s what the current formula does with onedit.  I just want it to do it on a time based trigger instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function namethatsheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rgA = ['B2', 'E2', 'B8', 'E8', 'B14', 'E14', 'B20', 'E20'];
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Control Panel');
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getName() != 'CONTROL PANEL');
  shts.forEach((sh, i) => {
    sh.setName(dsh.getRange(rgA[i]).getValue());
  });
}
```

Comment: Last question… will this change each tab or only one?  Will test in a minute.  So B2 is supposed to change tab 2, E2 is supposed to change tab 3, B8 tab 4 and so on.  Does this code do that? If not, what do I need to add to the code so it changes each specific tab?  I apologize for my ignorance when it comes to this.